# Lemma 2.1 in Undergraduate Analysis by Serge Lang: Rolle's Theorem or not?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

On page 70 of *Undergraduate Analysis* (2nd ed.), by Serge Lang, the following Lemma (2.1) is given:

> Let $f$ be differentiable on the open interval $a<x<b$ and let $c$ be a number such that $f(c)$ is a maximum, that is $$f(c)\ge f(x) \quad \text{for} \quad a<x<b.$$ Then $f'(c)=0$.

Now, I recognize this as Rolle's Theorem, except that it is not stipulated that $f(a)=f(b)$. I have a counter-example. What if $f(x)=x$? Then $c=b$ and $f'(c)=1$.

Comment: You must have $a <c <b $.

Comment: Given the wording, $a<c<b$, so your example is not a counter-example, since it doesn't attain a maximum in that open interval

Comment: It is true that $c$ must be in the interior of the interval but the wording of the lemma as supplied does not bind $c$ to be anywhere at all except in the domain of $f$.  If this is word-for-word what is in the book then it is an omission.

Comment: Technically, the wording does not preclude $c$ being outside the interval $(a,b)$, but this hypothesis is necessary. Lang is being sloppy here, hardly the first time.

Comment: @Hayden I understand now. It is a bit hidden.

Comment: @JasonKnapp I agree.

Comment: Rolle's theorem is Lemma 2.2 . In the literature Lemma 2.1 is often called  just _interior extremum theorem_.

Comment: The statement here is not really Rolle's theorem. I've heard of it being called Fermat's theorem, though I don't know the history...

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points)).

Comment: @TonyPiccolo Thanks for the link to the discussion of Fermat's theorem. I just saw that as a name for it in Stewart's calc book.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo can you please upgrade your [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481705/lemma-2-1-in-undergraduate-analysis-by-serge-lang-rolles-theorem-or-not#comment3017632_1481705) to an answer so that I can accept it?